# self.screen._incrementudc() error and turtle.Terminator error when I try to create a snake game

Tags: python

I was trying to create a Snake game by looking at videos in youtube. But unfortunately, the person who posted the video is success in creating this game with the same code as below. But I am getting errors.

I am getting the square head of the snake. But my snake is not moving.

Please help me debug it so that my snake moves when I click a,s,w,d as you can see in the code.

My code below:

```
    import turtle
    import time

    delay = 0.1
# set the screen
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.title("Snake Peek-a-Boo Game ")
    wn.bgcolor("pink")
    wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
    wn.tracer(0)  # screen updates

# Snake head
    head = turtle.Turtle()
    head.speed(0)
    head.shape("square")
    head.color("Black")
    head.penup()
    head.goto(0, 0)
    head.direction = "stop"


# functions
def go_up():
    head.direction = "up"


def go_down():
    head.direction = "down"


def go_left():
    head.direction = "left"


def go_right():
    head.direction = "right"


def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

    # keyboard
    wn.listen()

    wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")

    wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")

    wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")

    wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")


while True:
    wn.update()

    move()

    time.sleep(delay)

    wn.mainloop()

---------------------------------END OF CODE--------------------
My error below:

 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  line 197, in runfile
  pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
   line 69, in <module>
    wn.update()
  line 1303, in update
    t._update_data()
  line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in Python plays an important role in the syntax (unlike in languages like C++, where white spaces generally don't matter), so if following someone else's code, always pay attention to the white spaces as well, because they influence the program's logic.

In the code you posted, there are 2 problems:

1. The block containing the event listeners (from `wn.listen()` to `wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")`) should not be indented. Since you accidentally indented it, Python thinks it belongs to the `move()` function. This will still work, because it will be executed in each iteration of the while loop, but I would move it outside the scope of the `move()` function.
2. The bigger issue: `wn.mainloop()` is also indented, which causes it to become part of the `while` loop. You should remove the indentation to run `wn.mainloop()` on its own.

Try the following:

```
def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

# keyboard
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")

while True:
    wn.update()
    move()
    time.sleep(delay)
    
wn.mainloop()
```

Additionally, it seems like the `move` function contains some movement-related bugs as well, because you are executing the same code for up and down, and the same code for left and right movement. I suggest you take a look at the lines `head.sety(y + 20)` in `down` and `head.setx(x + 20)` in `left()` to debug your code.